# Merge two rows with a unique attribute

Tags: php, mysql, sql, max

This is a sample output of my table(time_entries)

```
user_name| entry_type   | entry_datetime
 User1   |   Time In    | 28-JUL-13  16:40:40
 User1   |   Time Out   | 28-JUL-13  16:40:41
 User2   |   Time In    | 28-JUL-13  16:41:13
 User2   |   Time Out   | 28-JUL-13  16:41:15
 User1   |   Time In    | 27-JUL-13  16:42:30
 User1   |   Time Out   | 27-JUL-13  16:42:34
 User2   |   Time In    | 27-JUL-13  16:43:32
 User2   |   Time Out   | 27-JUL-13  16:43:35
```

Now I used this query

```
SELECT te.user_name, te.entry_name, MAX(te.entry_datetime) AS date
FROM time_entries AS te
GROUP BY te.entry_type, te.user_name
```

and the result is this

```
user_name| entry_type   | entry_datetime
 User1   |   Time In    | 28-JUL-13  16:40:40
 User1   |   Time Out   | 28-JUL-13  16:40:41
 User2   |   Time In    | 28-JUL-13  16:41:13
 User2   |   Time Out   | 28-JUL-13  16:41:15
```

**QUESTION:** Is there a way to merge username with the same name in 1 line? and have an output something like this.

```
user_name|  Date     | Timein   | Timeout
User1    | 28-JUL-13 | 16:40:40 | 16:40:41
User2    | 28-JUL-13 | 16:41:13 | 16:41:15
```

I'm a little confuse how to do it.

Comment: you want to do it in php?

Comment: yah.. I'm using php.. Is it possible?

Comment: Is there a reason not to do that on sql side?

Comment: oh I mean I want to do it in sql my bad. something like my sample query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would approach it in this manner:

1. Create a query that returns the "time in" time for each user and date.
2. Create a query like #1 that returns the "time out" time for each user and date.
3. Merge the results together using LEFT JOIN.

The end result:

```
SELECT te.user_name, LEFT(te.entry_datetime, 10) AS entry_date, cin.entry_datetime AS timein, cout.entry_datetime AS timeout
FROM time_entries te
LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_name, LEFT(entry_datetime, 10) AS entry_date, MIN(entry_datetime) AS entry_datetime
    FROM time_entries
    WHERE entry_type = 'Time In'
    GROUP BY user_name, entry_date
) cin ON cin.user_name = te.user_name AND cin.entry_date = LEFT(te.entry_datetime, 9)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_name, LEFT(entry_datetime, 10) AS entry_date, MAX(entry_datetime) AS entry_datetime
    FROM time_entries
    WHERE entry_type = 'Time Out'
    GROUP BY user_name, entry_date
) cout ON cout.user_name = te.user_name AND cout.entry_date = LEFT(te.entry_datetime, 10)
GROUP BY te.user_name, entry_date;
```

[**Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c984/3)

Btw, I'm using `LEFT()` here because your column doesn't contain an actual date format that MySQL understands.

Comment: thanks dude.. your solution is working, but still have to weight in which is the best solution here because all solutions here is working.

Comment: @bot There will be a difference when a "time in" or "time out" entry is missing for a particular day. My answer will give `NULL` for those missing entries, which I believe is the correct behaviour.

Comment: yah.. I noticed it. That gives it a unique feature compare to the answer of others. thanks. :)

Comment: This will also not work when there is more than one entry for a user in a single day.

Comment: @Ruben It should, because both sub queries have a `group by`. Are you referring to something in particular?

Comment: @Jack You're grouping by user_name and entry_date. entry_date is the date part of the entry_datetime column, so if you have for example two entries on one day (for example 2013-07-28) you get two rows for the Time In and two rows for the Time Out. In the first join you get the MIN date and in the other join the MAX, so you will only get one row in the end result.

Comment: @Ruben I fail to see the issue here. Could you perhaps modify the fiddle and show me?

Comment: @Jack Sure. I made a new fiddle and changed the dates in the test rows to all be on july 28th. So both user1 and user2 have two entries (4 rows) on the 28th of July. Because of the group by in your query you only get one row per user per day, so in this case you get two rows as the end result instead of four. See this fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c984/2

Comment: @Ruben Ugh, I can't count; it should be `LEFT(entry_date, 10)` of course ... I see what you mean though and the question doesn't make that very obvious. I just assumed a daily tally was the requirement :)

Comment: @Jack The 9 vs 10 isn't the problem though, it's the GROUP BY user_name,entry_date that causes this behavior. But you're right in that it's not clear if there can be multiple entries per day, I just assumed it would be possible because it seems like some kind of visitor statistics data.

Comment: @Jack dude I found a loop hole in your solution for my case :(. Actually your solution is great but there is a problem. Some of the employees in our company works overnight and time.out the following day. Look at this http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e10e/1. I'm thinking just to make the job easier just remove ENTRY_DATE and only have 3 columns user_name, timein and timeout.Can you help me with it? thanks.

Comment: @bot Perhaps it would be better to ask another question, given that the specs have changed :)

Answer (score 3):

What about this?

```
select
user_name,
date(entry_datetime) as date,
min(entry_datetime) as Timein,
max(entry_datetime) as Timeout
from (
  SELECT te.user_name, te.entry_name, MAX(te.entry_datetime) AS date
  FROM time_entries AS te
  GROUP BY te.entry_type, te.user_name) src
group by user_name, date
```

Comment: `SELECT te.user_name, te.entry_name, MAX(te.entry_datetime) AS date
  FROM time_entries AS te
  GROUP BY te.entry_type, te.user_name` if u select data from this than i think max and min date is always same

Comment: this returns an error message Unknown column 'entry_datetime' in 'field list'

Comment: @bot where it wrriten from the subquery write table name simply it will work for this dataset instead of subquery write tablenane of your table

Comment: @bot replace subquery part with MAX(te.entry_datetime) AS entry_datetime

Comment: thanks dude.. your solution is working, but still have to weight in which is the best solution here because all solutions here is working.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a php side solution on how you can process the data.

```
function transformArray($data) {
   $final = array();
   foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
      if (!isset($final[$row['u']])) $final[$row['u']] = array('user' => $row['u']);
      $final[$row['u']][$row['t']] = date("H:i:s", strtotime($row['entrydatetime']));
      $final[$row['u']]['date'] = date("d:M:y", strtotime($row['entrydatetime']));
   }

   return $final;
}
```

You can pass it a data set that looks like this, you can adjust the field names as nessecery.

```
$data = array(
         array('u' => 'user1', 't' => 'TimeIn', 'entrydatetime' => '28-JUL-13  16:40:40'),
         array('u' => 'user1', 't' => 'TimeOut', 'entrydatetime' => '28-JUL-13  16:40:40'),
         array('u' => 'user2', 't' => 'TimeIn', 'entrydatetime' => '28-JUL-13  16:40:40'),
         array('u' => 'user2', 't' => 'TimeOut', 'entrydatetime' => '28-JUL-13  16:40:40')
);
```

Comment: thanks dude.. your solution is working, but still have to weight in which is the best solution here because all solutions here is working.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job:

```
SELECT te.user_name,DATE(te.entry_datetime) as Date,te.entry_datetime AS TimeIn,te2.entry_datetime AS TimeOut
FROM time_entries te
JOIN time_entries te2 ON te.user_name=te2.user_name AND te2.entry_type="Time Out" AND
  te2.entry_datetime=
  (
    SELECT 
      entry_datetime
    FROM 
      time_entries
    WHERE entry_type='Time Out' AND user_name=te.user_name AND entry_datetime > te.entry_datetime
    ORDER BY 
      ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, te.entry_datetime, `entry_datetime`))
    LIMIT 1
  )
WHERE te.entry_type="Time In";
```

Edit: a little explanation:

It selects the user_name, the date part and the entry_datetime for the TimeIn part. Then it joins on the same table to fetch the Time Out datetime part. It does this by selecting the entry with type "Time Out" with the same user_name and the date that is closest to the Time In datetime.

Comment: thanks dude.. your solution is working, but still have to weight in which is the best solution here because all solutions here is working.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
user_name,
dATE(entry_datetime) AS date1,
min(entry_datetime) as Timein,
max(entry_datetime) as Timeout
from time_entries
group by user_name, date1
```

[**SqlFiddleDemo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89d26/8)

> This Query will work appropriately when for every Time_In there is
>   corresponding timeout. and each and every  new day entry type should
>   start with time_in

Comment: This will not work when there are multiple entries for a user in 1 day though.

Comment: @Ruben see updated answer.....if it meet that requirement then it will give right result no matter how much time user make time in and out